# DIfferentiating partials inside ajax result

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a ajax request

```
$.ajax({
        url: url
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(result) {

           #I will received two different partials into this and i want to differentiate them.
           # I am planning to differentiate them with div ids of the conatiners embedding the partials. 
           #If i use
           if( $(result).find("#divid1").id =="divid1")
           {
                 # do something with the partial.
           }
           else
            {
                 # do something with second partial.
            }



        },

    });
```

If the result contains the second partial. The code is stopping at the if loop. Is there a way to check if the result conatins a particular div id and if not do some other thing in the else block ??

Edit ::

Sry, if my question is not clear. My ajax returns me html. But it is not the total html file its is part of the html file(partial). This partial is a bootstrap container with content inside it. My purpose hear is that I want to add this partial to the already existing html on my view. So I have the possibility of two partials to be returned in the result to Ajax, and I want to differentiate them.

Comment: Question not clear... at all! What does your ajax return exactly? can you show us the url file code?

Comment: what is a `partial`?

Comment: If you're post-processing returned HTML I'd suggest something else is probably wrong, e.g., architectural. Maybe returning JSON w/ embedded HTML would be easier, although that sounds equally horrible.